# why does curl return only rss feed content instead of html when there is an auto discovery link on the page?

Tags: curl, rss, autodiscovery

I have a home page with this link in the head section:

```
 <link href="/featured.rss" rel="alternate" title="Feature of the Day" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Maind you, this is on a regular html page with divs, formatting, content etc.

One day I used curl to ping the homepage just to check if the site was up.  I was expecting the raw html to be returned.  But interestingly curl and wget only give back the content of the rss feed.

1) Why is that happening?  Is this a feature of autodiscovery link that I'm not aware of?

2) What flags do I pass curl to get back the html text I was expecting?

Comment: cURL in what context? The PHP usage or from Unix?

Comment: curl from the terminal on the command line